# Control method advice for Markov (?) process

Tags: control

I'm experimenting with a device for tuning piano strings. It attaches to the piano's tuning pins and turns them slightly by applying a torque impulse. It is a semi-automatic process, handled by a human operator.

1. Operator presses a piano key, control system records the tone and calculates the frequency error. (The set frequency is known.)
2. The control system calculates the required size of the torque impulse.
3. The device applies the torque impulse.
4. The operator presses the key again. If pitch error is still large, repeat from 1.

The change in frequency caused by a torque impulse is a function of the impulse size and the current frequency of the string.

I'm now going to design a control system for this. So far I've found that it probably is a Markov process, since it is not time dependent and not depends on previous states. But what could be a suitable control method for this application?

Comment: Wouldn't the string frequency be proportional to it's length?  See [Mersenne's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne%27s_laws). It seems easier to put an encoder on there and do position control.

Comment: Interesting point. But the problem with position control is that it requires a device that can deliver much higher continuous torque and it will be challenging to come up with something that can be handheld.

Comment: I don’t know why you believe the control method affects the required amount of torque needed to move the tuning pegs.  The device has to move the pegs through a certain angle - how that angle is determined and achieved should not affect the selection of the motive means.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: You could probably model this sufficiently well with the following discrete time model $f_{n+1}=f_n+a\,u_n$ with $f_n$ the frequency and $u_n$ the applied impulse (the gain $a$ might change as a function of $f_n$ and other parameters). I suspect that a PI controller might be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

What a great idea! Here are some things I'd look out for, based on my experience tuning the pianos I have had over the years. (Not that I'm a pro, just trying to postpone calling in the pro.)

The tuning pins stick in place (obviously, otherwise they would immediately untwist!). A tuner must apply some torque to a pin, just to get it unstuck, before actually tuning the string. The necessary torque "used up" to get unstuck will vary from pin to pin, even on the same note, even on the same pin (if I pull it too sharp, back off, and try again).

Neither is there any reliable relation between delta-torque (actually delta-pin-angle) and delta-pitch, given the variability from string to string due to age, stiffness, even string manufacturer.

There are general trends, of course. Treble strings are under more tension than fat floppy bass strings. Shorter strings need tinier increments than longer ones. Wurlitzers and Yamahas and Steinways all behave differently. If it's way flat you need to bring it up more.

With all that variability, I wouldn't expect to be able to compute and apply a single impulse that would both unstick a pin and stretch its string to bring it into tune. Instead, I would expect a series of smaller impulses to ease it into place. More like a BZZZzzz or a squeeeeek instead of a quick double BANGbang. But listening and predicting would certainly speed the operation, even if it's not all at once.

The controller would want to listen to the string while those smaller impulses are in progress, sampling the pitch continuously, even from a single key strike, as it draws up the pitch. (Of course it would listen for the key strike, not wait for a trigger push). Doing just one sample and one impulse per key strike seems tedious.

I'm not even sure it works to reach a pitch exactly and expect it stay there. Does it unwind a teeny bit before the pin's static friction can "bite"? If so, the tuner has to go the same teeny bit sharp to compensate.

You know (or soon will) how complicated the relationship is between physical frequency and perceptual pitch, and how zero crossings of the waveform hardly anything to do with either (because of how the higher harmonics are non-harmonically sharp -- the string stiffness shortens the effective length). A related thing I have never quite understood is whether you want all strings for a given note to be in exact unison, or whether a certain richness or "fatness" comes from faint detuning.

If you'll forgive some brainstorming: It would be interesting for an upsell product in your product line to automatically manage muting the strings that you're not tuning, the thing the humans use the felts for. Also it would be interesting if the controller, besides listening to the strings, could excite them (speaker or electromagnetics, as well as mic). That wouldn't supplant the keyboard operation, but could complement it. Finally, the top-of-the-line model would move from pin to pin all by itself. If built into the piano, finally a product deserving the name "Auto-Tune"!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods to pose this problem. The good news is, that you are right, and it is a time-invariant system, if you consider multiple keystrokes for tuning one key.

I have no idea about the intricacies of piano/guitar/other string instrument tuning, but it might be worthwhile to check if it is a [linear time invariant system](https://courses.washington.edu/bioen302/Lecture/302_LTI_Control_notes.pdf).

If you do not want to/cannot go down the LTI route, you can just disregard any highly theoretical controls approach and try an intuitive approach, similar to what you described in your steps, but instead of trying to come up with a torque value in step 2, you just use increments, a constant large increment if you are far away, constant small increment if you are close.

You can see a guitar tuning variant explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJltXLUTFHk).
A detailed description of a different motorized guitar tuning solution can be found [here](https://www2.spsc.tugraz.at/www-archive/downloads/MGT_documentation.pdf).

Obviously Machine Learning can also be used to solve this problem. You can pose it as a reinforcement learning problem, where your action space is either discrete (small increment to tighten or to loosen) or continuos (the torque range) your observation space could be the current value of the torque (for the increments) or the frequency response. The reward function is how far you are form the ideal frequency. This would be the lease efficient way to do it, but probably the most fun one...

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking into those guitar tuners too, but the problem is that piano tuning pins require much more torque and such a device would be impractical. This flywheel approach can be made very compact and more practical, if it works.

I don't mind going down the LTI route, but find it hard to describe this system as an LTI system. It is stationary in every sampling instant, hence has no dynamics to it (?). The current state is independent of previous states. Can it still be described as an LTI system but without any dynamics?

Comment: The dynamics comes in response to an excitation. It think hitting the key is only a necesary condition to the excitation to occurre and can be (falsely) considered as the inout signal. The torque on the setting screw is the excitation. That certainly changes the output signal.